Cannot register SHIR(ADF) on Azure VM
As I mentioned on the title I'm trying to register a SHIR(ADF) on Azure VM but the error has occurred.
The error message and the log were like below.


According to a MS document, the solution like this case is 'using a public endpoint instead of a private endpoint' but I have to use private network because of my company policy.
MS document
Does anybody know other solution?
Any answer would be helped.
Thank you.

Failed to get service token from ADF service with key IR****@xxxDataFactory@ServiceEndpoint=<datafactoryNmae>.<region>.datafactory.azure.net@****************** and time cost is: 3.8236143 seconds, the error code is: Unexpected Fault, activityId is: 40797b25-a932-4e79-86dd-ccbcd4d7cf7f and detailed error message is An error occurred while sending the request.
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host


To resolve the above error, after enabling private endpoint in the factory, note down the IP address of the DNS configuration.
In the Azure VM, go to  C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc, and open the host file in Notepad. Add the line that maps the private IP to the FQDN at the end of the file, and save the change.
    xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx <df-name>.<region>.datafactory.azure.net


If a self-hosted integration runtime is already created, regenerate the key. Use that key to register SHIR, and it will register and connect to ADF successfully as shown below:

For more information, you can refer to the  MS Question.
